# AWS ssh access 'port 22: Operation timed out' issue

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-keys

I can't access to AWS EC2 instance from one day.
(AMI: ubuntu/images/ebs/ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64-server-20121001 (ami-22ad1223))

```
$ ssh -v -i mykey.pem ubuntu@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

This is my "Security Groups" setting in EC2. 
I did not change the setting from the time had a good connection.

```
Ports  Protocol  Source
22      tcp     0.0.0.0/0
80      tcp     0.0.0.0/0
3000    tcp     0.0.0.0/0
3006    tcp     0.0.0.0/0
```

I've tried many times to restart the server.
Web server is going well. However SSH connection is not.

What could be problem and how to make it work?

Comment: If you restarted it, are you using the current IP address?

Comment: Do you have any outbound rules configured on the security group?

Comment: Outbound rules are not blocking the communication if the connection is not initiated from the server. But Network ACL rules may block it.

Comment: In my case I enabled Nginx and that blocked my ssh connections.

Answer (score 18):

My usual checklist:

- On AWS console: is the Instance up and healthy?
- Is it in a public Subnet?
- Does it have a public ip?
- Does the VPC have an associated Internet Gateway?
- Does it have the Routing Table to the Internet Gateway? (Attached to the subnet?)
- Are the Network ACL rules default?
- Does the Security group allow ping? If yes, does the ping work?
- Does the Security group allow SSH inbound?

If there is still no clue, then fire up a new instance (from a base AMI) in the same VPC. Connect to it via SSH. If it was successful, try to ssh from that instance.

Comment: This checklist is really nice! If you're like me and everything was perfect (but still not able to connect), try changing your internet provider. I had to disconnect my home wifi, then connect to internet using my phone's hotspot, and then I was able to successfully SSH into my EC2 instance. Funny thing is I was then able to switch back to home wifi and suddenly SSH worked, so I didn't have to stay on hotspot.

Comment: I would also add: "Is your instance throttled in CPU credits?". The outcome is the same: SSH timeout.

Answer (score 14):

I too faced the same issue. Actually, by mistake, I deleted the default Internet Gateway.

1. Go to VPC and click "Internet Gateways" from the left menu.
2. Click "Create internet gateway" button and provide Name tag (any name - optional) and click create.
3. By default, it is detached. So click the Actions drop-down and select "Attach to VPC" and attach it with default VPC
4. Now go to "Route Table" and select default route table and edit the route by clicking "Edit routes" button under Routes tab
5. Then in the Destination text box provide "0.0.0.0/0" and in target select the newly created Internet gateway (starts with igw-alphanumeric) and save the route.

Now you should be able to SSH EC2 instance.

Comment: This was exactly my case, the only problem is I saw your answer right after I accidentally found out that the internet gateway is not associated with route table! Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 5):

For newbies to AWS, like me, remember the hostname can change if you reboot or stop/start your instances. So remember to use the right hostname - visible in the description of your instance each time you ssh.

Answer (score 3):

If this happens "from one day", the IP your AWS EC2 instance associated with may be blocked from this day.
If the IP is blocked, you need to add a new dynamic IP and associate this new dynamic IP with your AWS EC2 instance.
Steps:
1.Go to "Elastic IPs".
2.Allocate new address.
3.Choose this new address. Click "Actions" and "Associate address".
4.Select your instance and Click "Associate".
In my case, adding new dynamic IP to my AWS EC2 instance fix the problem.(My problem was I can't access to AWS EC2 instance from one day too)

Comment: thank you so much, i spent almost the entire day researching and trying different things, and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly create a new security group and select type SSH

SSH
TCP
22
0.0.0.0/0

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Adam's answer, also check if your public subnet's RT table is using the IGW and the private Subnets' RT has 0.0.0.0/0 -> NAT instance Id.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are connecting to the public dynamic IP or associate an ElasticIP and connect to it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Even after setting up ElasticIP I still have the same problem. I check my firewall and it is not on at my local machine. What else should I check to make sure? By the way, I am from Malaysia and my server is Oregon. Would that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

If none of the troubleshooting steps above work for you, make sure that your EC2 container meets all system requirements for the application(s) you're running on the container. SSH will sometimes not be able to start if the memory runs out before getting to the SSH service.

Example: I was perfectly able to SSH into my EC2 container when I first launched it. I then proceeded to install Mailcow. My  issue with SSH arose after restarting my container because the application I had installed required heavy services -- Docker, for example. After reading the system requirements from Mailcow, I realized a t2.micro wasn't even close to what I needed to run everything. I changed to a t3.large, and all worked perfectly.

Even after doing this for awhile, you can sometimes forget the most basic steps and requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was using public wifi in the library and that was not letting me connect, which I came to know when I switched to my mobile hotspot wifi (password protected). Try switching to a protected network.

Answer (score 0):

Even I also faced this same problem, good to know i have not allowed from route table.

Check EC2 Instance associated

And try these steps

1. subnet,Route table and allowed CIDR blocks
2. key pair associated with EC2 Instance
3. security group ssh port 22 allowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing from a new machine, then make sure the IP of the machine you are accessing from is included in the inbound rules. If not add a rule
SSH | TCP | Port:22 | Source: MY IP

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to delete all my rules for the security group for the particular instance and create new rules for the same ssh, http and https

For some reason after stopping the instance and starting it later, my IP changed... probably because I switched my wifi connectivity device.

But putting new rules with the new IP address worked! You can check the ip by googling "myip"

Answer (score 0):

Well, if this happened all of a sudden, try disconnecting and connecting back to your VPN (if accessing through a VPN). It might work!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fixed it simply by following this instruction

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html

It sets up your private key pair as well as security group. The issue I think mainly because the default security group doesn't has a ssh inbound for your local IP setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't restarted the ec2 instance(as you have to use new ip address in that case) and have the following in inbound rules of security Port range 22 Protocol TCP Source 0.0.0.0/0,
Make sure to check the Network ACLs and make sure inbound rules are correctly set on it to allow ssh traffic.

Answer (score -1):

Try stopping the ec2 instance and then restarting. It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

in my case the issue was with my internet, I simply changed the internet connection of my laptop and it working.

Comment: How could you improve this answer to make it more helpful and more reproducible?